# Как создать массив из диапазона чисел в Golang?

Tags: массивы, golang

Мне необходимо создать массив из целых чисел с диапазоном 91-97 и 65-123.
В Python можно сделать так `list(range(91, 97))` и вы получите массив с диапазоном чисел [91,92,93,94,...]. Можно ли сделать что-то подобное в Golang? Пока реализовал вот так, через функцию, но не уверен, что это правильно.

```
var continueChar []int
var alphabetChar []int

func fillCharArray(arr *[]int, start, finish int) {
    for i := start; i <= finish; i++ {
        *arr = append(*arr, i)
    }
}

func main() {
    fillCharArray(&continueChar, 91, 97)
    fillCharArray(&alphabetChar, 65, 123)

    fmt.Println(continueChar) // [91 92 93 94 95 96 97]
    fmt.Println(alphabetChar) // [65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](https://play.golang.org/p/TJLCB0XkdOG)

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   result := getRange(91, 98)
   fmt.Println(result)
}

func getRange(start uint, end uint) (result []uint) 
{
   result = make([]uint, 0, end - start)
   for value := start; value <= end; value ++{
     result = append(result, value)
   }

   return result
}
```